# jQuery cycle plugin dynamic timeout for images and videos

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I am using jQuery Cycle plugin to rotate a mix of images and FLV videos. For images I have fixed timeout duration of 3000ms but for videos its based on the video length and that's where my problem starts. I am always getting the duration of my first video as:

```
var value = 0;

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slideshow').cycle({

    fx:'scrollLeft,scrollRight',
    speed:   1500,
    timeoutFn: valueFn
    });

 function valueFn(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward){

  value = parseInt($('#duration').val());
  return value;
 }
});
...
...
<div id="image">

 <ul class="slideshow">
  <?php
  $dir = "media/images";

  if (is_dir($dir)) {
     if (($dh = opendir($dir))) {
        $i = 0;
        $name = 'FLVPlayer';
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
          if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
              continue;

          $ext = explode(".", $file);
          if (@$ext[1] == null)
               continue;

     switch ($ext[1]) {
      case "jpg":
       echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"duration\" name=\"val\" value=\"3000\" />
       <li><img src=\"media/images/" . $file . "\" width=\"848\" height=\"608\" /></li>";
       break;
      case "flv":
       $flv = fopen("media/images/".$file, "rb");
       fseek($flv, -4, SEEK_END);
       $arr = unpack('N', fread($flv, 4));
       $last_tag_offset = $arr[1];
       fseek($flv, -($last_tag_offset + 4), SEEK_END);
       fseek($flv, 4, SEEK_CUR);
       $t0 = fread($flv, 3);
       $t1 = fread($flv, 1);
       $arr = unpack('N', $t1 . $t0);
       $milliseconds_duration = $arr[1];
       $milliseconds_duration;

$html = <<<HTML
                <input type="hidden" id="duration" value="{$milliseconds_duration}" />
                <li>
                <div id="container{$i}">Loading the player ...</div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                               jwplayer("container{$i}").setup({

 flashplayer: "js/player.swf",
 file: "media/images/{$file}",
 height: 608,
 width: 848,
 "controlbar.idlehide": true,
 icons: false,
 events: {
     onReady: function() { this.play(); }
  }
 });

 </script>
</li>  

HTML;

 echo $html;
 $i++;
 break;
 case "txt":
          $myFile = "media/images/" . $file;
          $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
          $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
          fclose($fh);
          echo "<li>" . $theData . "</li>";
          break;
   }
  }
 }
closedir($dh);
}
?>
```

the PHP code simply goes through a directory, looks for files and echos out the appropriate HTML code for FLV, images or text. If I use a fixed timeout value then everything else works just fine.

Comment: `I am always getting the duration of my first video as...` I'm on the edge of my seat. Zero? Is your valueFn function returning the correct value? Do your hidden flv inputs have the correct values in them?

Comment: yes it's actually the value of the first slide that stays and wont't get updated. So now I tried a picture to be the first element with timeout of 3000 and every other slide gets the same no matter what timeout value I set for them.

Comment: As you can see the hidden field gets updated with video lengt     div id="image">
<ul class="slideshow">
<input type="hidden" id="duration" value="60786" />
<li>
<div id="container0">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container0").setup({
flashplayer: "js/player.swf",
file: "media/images/1.flv",
height: 608,
width: 848,
"controlbar.idlehide": true,
icons: false,
events: {
onReady: function() { this.play(); }
}
});
</script>
</li> <input type="hidden" id="duration" name="val" value="3000" />
<li><img src="media/images/1.jpg" width="848" height="608" /></li>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are outputting a number of images and videos onto a single page, however, they all have the same id - `duration.` Id's must be unique. Otherwise this line

```
value = parseInt($('#duration').val());
```

is just going to grab the first element that has that id and get its value. Perhaps you should consider using the html5 [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to hold your video lengths.

```
<div id="item1" data-length="3000"></div>
var time = $('currElement').attr('data-length');
```

Or you need to give the hidden elements unique id's and get them another way.

Comment: I am getting an undefined value now :(

Comment: another thought: is it possible to pause the cycling from within the jwplayer and resume after the video has completed?

Comment: See the cycle documentation. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html It documents the pause and resume calls.

Comment: thank you for answer. I am new to JavaScript, how would I pause the cycle from outside of jQuery but within JavaScript?

Comment: Finally got it. The best solution is simply calling 'pause' and 'resume' from within the jwplayer events handler do the trick. I love jquery, cycle plugin, jwplayer and the great folks here :)